# Toggle current class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to toggle `.title` class when we click on .title `.content` class toggle.Here i written this classes inside .I want to be toggle .title in a current class. I tried but not getting. Can anyone suggest me what might be the issue here?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol class="list-timeline">
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">The Establishment</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Ascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse pellentesque convallis massa.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">150 Employee</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: `.content` is inside of `.list-timeline`, not `.title`, which is adjacent to it. The `find` method looks inside of the element you call it on, so it had no chance to find the div you wanted to have it work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `parent` to find class `content`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol class="list-timeline">
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">The Establishment</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Ascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse pellentesque convallis massa.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">150 Employee</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Alternative way using `next`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ol class="list-timeline">
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">The Establishment</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Ascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse pellentesque convallis massa.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">150 Employee</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(this).find` will look for content inside of that element.
`$(this).parent().find` will look for the content inside of the elements parent

`$(this).parent().find('.content').slideToggle();`

Answer (score 1):

You were find in title tag but first you should select parent then you find which one you want to select.

I think you want like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').on('click','.title', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').find('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.content {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
  <ol class="list-timeline">
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">The Establishment</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Ascetur ridiculus mus. Suspendisse pellentesque convallis massa.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h3 class="title">150 Employee</h3>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus.</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
if($('...').hasClass('content')) {
    $('...').addClass('title').removeClass('content');    
}

if($('...').hasClass('title')) {
    $('...').addClass('content').removeClass('title');    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `siblings` as

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.title').click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

instead of going up the parent. `next` is also an option as mentioned already.